# When should I use the "node_view" cache tag?

Tags: 8, caching

When should I use the *node_view* cache tag?

```php
$build['#cache'] = ['tags' => [
    'node_view',
    // ...
]];
```

Drupal core uses the following code, in the [`EntityViewBuilder`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityViewBuilder.php/class/EntityViewBuilder/8.9.x) class.

```php
public function getCacheTags() {
  return [$this->entityTypeId . '_view'];
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a tag used by core (at least not outside test functions): https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-tags

Comment: @Hudri Yes, it is used in some tests (eg: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.2.x/core/modules/node/tests/src/Functional/Views/FrontPageTest.php). Maybe it is part of the core but not documented? Maybe it's part of the core but hard to find because of something like `$entity.'_'.$type`?

Comment: Yes, this tag is generic for all entities and is added by EntityViewBuilder which by the way is the only code in core which is using the tag to reset its own entity builds.

Comment: @4k4 Wow, thank you for this info! Should we use it in userland? I still don't get its purpose..

Comment: The purpose in core is to clear the entity builds from the render cache when the display configuration is changed. You don't need to invalidate the cache tag in custom code as long as you use the API to change this configuration.

Comment: Does it make sense to use it in userland? For example cache a page or a block? If I use it for a block then what must happen to invalitade the cache? What does that mean: `display configuration is changed`? Does it mean changing any calue in `/admin/structure/views/settings`? May you want to post an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: For nodes it means changing /admin/structure/types